# Array of objects values to array

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this :

```
obj = [{x:150, y:260},{x:160, y:545},{x:478, y:858},{x:125, y:560}]
```

and I want an array like this:

```
array = [150,260,160,545,478,858,125,560]
```

How can I do ?

Comment: e.g. ... `[{x:150, y:260},{x:160, y:545}].reduce((collector, item) => collector.concat(Object.values(item)), []);` ... making use of [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const obj = [{x:150, y:260},{x:160, y:545},{x:478, y:858},{x:125, y:560}]

const res = obj.flatMap(Object.values)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: `... .flatMap(Object.values)` already is sufficient ... no need for the additional callback.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Array.prototype.reduce

```js
const obj = [{x:150, y:260},{x:160, y:545},{x:478, y:858},{x:125, y:560}]

const arr = obj.reduce((acc, {x, y}) => acc.concat(x, y), [])

document.write(`arr = [${arr.join()}]`)
```

as suggested in the comments to make it more generic you can

```js
const obj = [{v: 100, x:150, y:260, z: 123},{x:160, y:545},{x:478, y:858},{x:125, y:560}]

const arr = obj.flatMap(Object.values)

document.write(`arr = [${arr.join()}]`)
```

Comment: Huh, didn't think about `concat`. Would there be any relevant difference instead of using `push` and returning the same array instead? that would be an interesting scenario.

Comment: @briosheje probably in some cases `.push` may have smaller memory usage, but with `.concat` is shorter because it returns the resulting array

Comment: do you mind changing this approach into something more generic that takes unknown key value pairs into account.

Answer (score 2):

Use `reduce` to make it in a single iteration. Otherwise, you can use `map` and `flat` or really many others, like `flatMap`.

Differently from `map + flat` or `flatMap`, `reduce` iterates the original array only once.
This likely is irrelevant in most scenarios, unless the array you're going to iterate is somewhat big.

```js
const obj = [{x:150, y:260},{x:160, y:545},{x:478, y:858},{x:125, y:560}];

const array = obj.reduce((acc, next) => {
  acc.push(...Object.values(next));
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
[{x:150, y:260},{x:160, y:545},{x:478, y:858},{x:125, y:560}].flatMap(obj => [obj.x,obj.y])
```

Answer (score 1):

iterate over the array and concatenate the values into a new common array.

```js
const obj = [{x:150, y:260},{x:160, y:545},{x:478, y:858},{x:125, y:560}];
let arr =[];

obj.forEach(function(item){
  arr = arr.concat(Object.values(item));
})


console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you can implement the following way using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [object destruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration) and [array destruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_the_rest_of_an_array_to_a_variable):

```js
const collection = [{x:150, y:260},{x:160, y:545},{x:478, y:858},{x:125, y:560}]
 
const arr = collection.reduce((acc, {x, y}) => [...acc, x, y], [])

console.log(arr)
```

I'd say it is a collection not an object, so let's name it to `collection` not obj.

Comment: What about `x`?